# about address of CUDA automatic array

Tags: memory, cuda, local-variables

I am new to CUDA and GPUs, and I am trying to understand how things work, especially how the memory is laid out.

The following piece of code :

```
#include <stdio.h>

__global__ 
void addr (long long unsigned int * b)
{
  int d[10];
  b[threadIdx.x] = (long long unsigned int)&d[0];
}


int main ()
{
  int i;
  long long unsigned int * bd, b[16];

  memset (b, 0, 16);
  cudaMalloc ((void**)&bd, 16 * sizeof (long long unsigned int)); 

  cudaMemcpy (bd, b, 16 * sizeof (long long unsigned int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice); 

  addr<<<1, 16>>>(bd);

  cudaMemcpy (b, bd, 16 * sizeof (long long unsigned int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost); 

  for (i = 0; i < 16; i++)
    printf ("%3d 0x%llx\n", i, b[i]);

  return 0;
}
```

Yields this result :

```
  0 0x3fffc48
  1 0x3fffc48
  2 0x3fffc48
  3 0x3fffc48
  4 0x3fffc48
  5 0x3fffc48
  6 0x3fffc48
  7 0x3fffc48
  8 0x3fffc48
  9 0x3fffc48
 10 0x3fffc48
 11 0x3fffc48
 12 0x3fffc48
 13 0x3fffc48
 14 0x3fffc48
 15 0x3fffc48
```

I was expecting different values for each thread. What happens here ?

Answer (score 1):

> What happens here ?

It is instructive to look at the code emitted by the compiler:

```
.version 6.2
.target sm_52
.address_size 64

    // .globl   _Z4addrPy

.visible .entry _Z4addrPy(
    .param .u64 _Z4addrPy_param_0
)
{
    .local .align 8 .b8     __local_depot0[40];
    .reg .b64   %SP;
    .reg .b64   %SPL;
    .reg .b32   %r<2>;
    .reg .b64   %rd<6>;


    mov.u64     %SPL, __local_depot0;
    cvta.local.u64  %SP, %SPL;
    ld.param.u64    %rd1, [_Z4addrPy_param_0];
    cvta.to.global.u64  %rd2, %rd1;
    mov.u32     %r1, %tid.x;
    mul.wide.u32    %rd3, %r1, 8;
    add.s64     %rd4, %rd2, %rd3;
    add.u64     %rd5, %SP, 0;
    st.global.u64   [%rd4], %rd5;
    ret;
}
```

`d` is stored in local memory. That has thread level scope. To the best of my knowledge, the documentation doesn't define how addressing or address spaces work for local memory.

If one was to speculate that each thread had its own private address space for local memory, it would seem logical that the first element of each threads local memory started at same address *in the thread local address space*. There may well be [TLB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_lookaside_buffer) translation to a unique address in a global memory bank. Again, all speculation.